# MySQL multi-column indexed only use first column

Tags: mysql, indexing

I have a MySQL table with about 40M+ rows.

The table has many columns and I have a sql below

```
select
  *
from
  `conversation`
where
  (
    `id` > 40000000
    AND `last_msg_timestamp` >= '2022-07-17 08:25:00.011'
    AND `status` = 8
  )
order by
  `id`
limit
  100
```

There are about 5M rows with status=8. So I created an index `idx_status_id_last_msg_timestamp` with columns (status, id, last_msg_timestamp)  to improve the query speed.

Now, I found that:

- 1: if `id>?` condition has a small value(less than 40M), it works well (about 3ms) and explain show index `idx_status_id_last_msg_timestamp` is used with key length=12
- 2: if `id>?` condition has a big value near max(id), the query is slow (about 1s) and explain show index `idx_status_id_last_msg_timestamp` is used with key length=4

I want to know why it only uses the status column in the index in case 2.

Thanks

Explain Info: Format=Json, the query take 0.877697 sec

```sql
explain format=json select
    *
from
  `conversation`
where
  (
    `id` > 40939363
    and `last_msg_timestamp` >= '2022-07-19 08:25:00.011'
    and `assign_status` = 8
  )
order by
  `id`
limit
  100
```

```json
{
    "query_block": {
        "select_id": 1,
        "cost_info": {
            "query_cost": "141199.15"
        },
        "ordering_operation": {
            "using_filesort": false,
            "table": {
                "table_name": "conversation",
                "access_type": "ref",
                "possible_keys": [
                    "PRIMARY",
                    "idx_status_id_lastmsgtimestamp"
                ],
                "key": "idx_status_id_lastmsgtimestamp",
                "used_key_parts": [
                    "status"
                ],
                "key_length": "4",
                "ref": [
                    "const"
                ],
                "rows_examined_per_scan": 117665,
                "rows_produced_per_join": 389,
                "filtered": "0.33",
                "index_condition": "((`conversation`.`status` <=> 8) and ((`conversation`.`id` > 40939363) and (`conversation`.`last_msg_timestamp` >= '2022-07-19 08:25:00.011')))",
                "cost_info": {
                    "read_cost": "117665.96",
                    "eval_cost": "77.86",
                    "prefix_cost": "141199.15",
                    "data_read_per_join": "325K"
                },
                "used_columns": [
                    "id",
                    "******",
                    "******",
                    "******",
                    "....",
                    "last_msg_timestamp",
                    "status"
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The *real* problem is the missing `AND`.  This may be  "valid" syntax, but it does not do what you want:

```
`id` > 40000000 `last_msg_timestamp` >= '2022-07-17 08:25:00.011'
```

`EXPLAIN` fails to show (in key_len) when it is using a column for a 'range' test (`id` > 40000000) or for `ORDER BY` (order by `id`)

`EXPLAIN FORMAT=JSON SELECT ...` does a better job.  (Please provide this.)

I believe that it did use at least 2 of the columns of

```
INDEX (status,     -- for filtering
       id,         -- at least for range filtering, possibly for ORDER BY
       last_msg_timestamp)   -- if used, it was not very useful
```

Another technique for getting insight:

```
FLUSH STATUS;
SELECT ...;
SHOW SESSION STATUS LIKE 'Handler%';
```

That will how many rows were actually touched -- probably more than 100 and less than the entire table.

For this type of query, I would consider a slight alteration in the "order by":

```
select  *
    from  `conversation`
    where `last_msg_timestamp` >= '2022-07-17 08:25:00.011'
      and  `status` = 8 
    order by  last_msg_timestamp, id
    limit  100
```

together with

```
INDEX(status, last_msg_timestamp, id)
```

With this change, it will be able to stop after no more than 100 rows in the index.

**More**  Give this a try

```
select  *
    from  ( SELECT id
            FROM `conversation`
            where  `id` > 40939363
              ANd  `last_msg_timestamp` >= '2022-07-19 08:25:00.011'
              AND  `assign_status` = 8 
            order by  `id`
            limit  100 ) AS x
    ORDER BY id
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. The missing `AND` is a typo. I have fixed  it and  added explain info to the question.  I can't follow the alteration solution because I have a job which scans all rows match the conditions for doing sth and  the `last_msg_timestamp` may change during the job running

Comment: @wdxfairy - I added another suggestion.

Comment: Thanks. The suggestion works well (with adding  `JOIN` to get all columns ).  Appending `force index(idx_status_id_lastmsgtimestamp)` to sql works, too.  I want to know why I get  `"used_key_parts" = ["status"]` with my original SQL.

Comment: @wdxfairy - Something like this...  "status" was the only column tested with '='.  The fact that "id>..." was also used was not shown.  The Handler trick I mentioned _should_ show that it does not scan the entire index.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem. After I deleted other indexes, it worked well. The index I deleted was an index built separately for the columns in the joint index.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34645397)